# Route traffic between two Linux PCs with DHCP-assigned addresses

Tags: routing, linux-networking

I have two Linux computers that are assigned IP addresses via DHCP by our corporate router.  The two computers are also connected directly together over another network port by an optical network cable for maximum speed.  (In case it matters department: The computers are actually high-end Macs, and the Linux computers are running in a VM on each.)  Currently, access to the world is fine over the main network port.  I think I want to create a new entry in the routing table that covers the specific case of communicating with the other Linux computer over the second device.  Does this sound reasonable?  Will the fact that the IP addresses are DHCP-assigned complicate things?

The computers are running the latest version of CentOS, if it matters.  TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DHCP-assigned addresses on the other interfaces don't matter, as the other interfaces themselves don't matter. Note that addresses are not assigned to machines, they are assigned to interfaces on machines. If you hear someone say "that machine has address ...", it usually means "the only network interface on that machine has address ...".

You first have to select an unused network, with addresses different than every other address you might want to use. You can pick something like `192.168.255.0`, assuming it is not used otherwise. Assign one address from this network (`192.168.255.1`) to the first machine on the optical network interface, another address from this network (`192.168.255.2`) to the second machine on the optical network interface. With that on a physical network you would have direct connection through your optical network cable. You now can access the machines with `192.168.255.1` and `192.168.255.2`.

As you have VMs, you first have to enable access to the physical interfaces. You have to add another virtual interface to the VMs and select type bridge. then select the physical interface with the optical network.

You don't need to set up any routing entries for this, the necessary entries will be created automatically.